# Angular: Using $http in a provider

Tags: angularjs

I've created an angular Provider which is exposing a `getSession` method which I need to resolve before going into a specific route:

```
var serviceId = 'session';

angular.module("app").provider(serviceId, sessionProvider);

function sessionProvider() {

    this.session = undefined;

    this.$get = function($http) {
        return {
            getSession: function () {
                return $http.get("/session-info")
                        .then(_onSuccess, _onError);
            }
        }
    }

    function _onSuccess(data) {
        return data.data;
    }

    function _onError(data) {
        return data;
    }
}
```

I then inject it into my config and try to use it:

```
angular.module("app").config([
            "$routeProvider", "$httpProvider", "sessionProvider", function 
                ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, sessionProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when("/", {
                    templateUrl: "app/home/home.html",
                    resolve: {
                        session: sessionProvider.getSession()
                    }
                });
            }
    ]);
```

But I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
    TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I'm not sure what I've done wrong here?

### Edit

When I try @DrogoNevets answer below:

```
function sessionProvider() {

    this.session = undefined;

    this.$get = function ($http) {
        return {
        }
    }

    this.getSession = function () {
        return $http.get("/session-info")
                    .then(_onSuccess, _onError);
    }

    function _onSuccess(data) {
        this.session = data.data;
        return data.data;
    }

    function _onError(data) {
        return data;
    }
}
```

I get the following error as I'm not able to inject `$http` into the provider itself, is that correct?

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
    ReferenceError: $http is not defined
```

Comment: Give a full error message

Comment: I have, the specific line is `session: sessionProvider.getSession()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to call getSession from the config part you need to assign it to `this` not within the `$get` part

try something like this:

```
function sessionProvider() {
    var session;

    this.$get = function() {
        return {
            getSession: this.getSession,
            setSession: this.setSession
        }
    }

    function _onSuccess(data) {
        return data.data;
    }

    function _onError(data) {
        return data;
    }


    this.getSession= function () {
        return session
    }

    this.setSession= function (id) {
        session = id;
    }
}
```

here is a fiddle showing what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/EQ86N/1/

Comment: But I need to use $http to make a request to get the information, is that possible?

Comment: yes just do the rest as you were, just don't modify the stucture of the functions, this was just a working example and I didnt have a URL to call to test $http with

Comment: Where would I inject $http because I thought I could only do it in the $get function, but I would need access to it in the getSession function from the sample above?

Comment: See my edit, thats what I thought would happen when I try to use $http